# Angular variables not work updated from 1.2 to 1.4

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my angular variables are not working :D Yeah its simple like that but let me explain it.. I updated my website from angular 1.2 to angular 1.4. All the angular animations are looking awesome and they work but angular variables not shown. Here this code from angular docs. I tried it in my site but results are same..

```
    <div ng-init="friends = [
          {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
          {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
          {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
          {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
          {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
          {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
          {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
          {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
          {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
          {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
        ]">
I have {{friends.length}} friends. They are:
<input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="filter friends..." aria-label="filter friends" />
<ul class="example-animate-container">
<li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:q as results">
[{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
</li>
<li class="animate-repeat" ng-if="results.length == 0">
<strong>No results found...</strong>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[it is looking like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiXYy.png)

What do you think about that? Are there a problem accured when I tried to update my angular version? Thank you so much

Comment: Open your console and look for errors!

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/2joy85fg/) fiddle contains the code above and it is working, with the exception that I added `ng-app="app"` and the necessary `angular.module(...)` call.

Comment: probably rpirsc13 is right but thank you so much Nikos Paraskevopoulos. You are great. tymeJV you are not -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrating from Angular 1.2 to 1.4 will require you to change your dependencies. There are many changes that will break your code.

For example:

- If using ngAnimate in 1.2 you are required to explicitly use angular-animate that matches the angular version. Just by looking at the little snippet of code that you provided I would say this is the case.
- If using cookies then the service has changed completely where you can only access cookies via it's getters and setters.

For a complete list please have a look here : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Comment: I was handled this ngAnimate angular-animate problem but I will check it again. thank you so much.